# What browser engine does Capacitor use

Tags: capacitor

We have some issues with elements that are rendered differently across devices.
So can this be because they use a different browser engine?
Is it a browser engine that the device provides or is it packed inside capacitor, and is there a way to set the version of this engine so every device uses the same engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Capacitor documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs) seems really good. According to those docs, the browser engine varies by environment.

- [On iOS](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios), it uses Apple's [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) (Safari-like).
- [On Android](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android), it uses an Android WebView with Chrome 60 or higher.
- [On Web](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/web), of course, it's up to the end user what gets used.

Comment: And is there a way I can see which version is used on a device? Like Device.getInfo() but I don’t see the browser engine version in there

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid

Comment: Device.getInfo() should be returning a webViewVersion value